# catkin_make command not found executing by a dockerfile

Tags: ros, docker, ros-kinetic, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am creating a dockerfile for creating automatically an Ubuntu 16.04 operation system on which ROS kinetic is installed.

Until now, my the building process of the dockerfile yields to the installation of Ubuntu 16.04 as well as ROS kinetic.
Unfortunately, the `RUN catkin_make` command inside inside of the dockerfile is not working in the building process, even executing the command `RUN /bin/bash -c "bash /ros_entrypoint.sh"` beforehand.

However, when I run the resulting docker image ( `sudo docker run -it <its hash-number>` ) and execute $`bash /ros_entrypoint.sh && cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin_make` in the Ubuntu shell, the `catkin_make` is working as you can see in the following image:

https://i.imgur.com/WcwHigJ.png

My goal is to achieve the same result with the building process of a dockerfile.
I am out of ideas, how I could achieve this.
Therefore I am asking for help.

I have already tried the answers of other questions, dealing with the almost same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635472/using-the-run-instruction-in-a-dockerfile-with-source-does-not-work/25998432#25998432

https://answers.ros.org/question/241834/extendingsourcing-the-ros-install-dir-in-a-dockerfiles-build-phase/

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/fd835d142e0571da7bfd4649e6bda8a015a0d8f8/.docker/source/Dockerfile#L27-L29

The current dockerfile, which needs to be improved, looks currently like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full

#### HACK, replacing shell with bash for later docker build commands
RUN mv /bin/sh /bin/sh-old && \
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN /bin/bash -c "bash /ros_entrypoint.sh"

RUN mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src/

RUN cd ~/catkin_ws/ && \
catkin_make
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312577/catkin_make-command-not-found-executing-by-a-dockerfile/) by [Daniel_1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/39436/daniel_1337/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-01-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-12**:
Please don't use an image to display text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from the image. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the text.

**Comment by [Daniel_1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/39436/daniel_1337/) on 2019-01-12**:
@jayess: The picuture is not important. It just shows that the commands(bash /ros_entrypoint.sh && cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin_make) are working, when I run the dockerfile.

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-04-28**:
Hello, I'm a beginner trying to understand Docker.
Could someone explain what does replacing shell with bash actually do?

```
#### HACK, replacing shell with bash for later docker build commands
RUN mv /bin/sh /bin/sh-old && \
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You dockerfile is a bit erratic, so I'll just provide a complete minimal example of building a ROS 1 package from source.
Just swap melodic for kinetic if that is the distro you still require; the following includes:
Cloning source code into workspace
Installing package dependencies
Building package using catkin tools
Sourcing workspace into entrypoint
And launching package nodes

```
FROM ros:melodic

# install build tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      python-catkin-tools \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# clone ros package repo
ENV ROS_WS /opt/ros_ws
RUN mkdir -p $ROS_WS/src
WORKDIR $ROS_WS
RUN git -C src clone \
      -b $ROS_DISTRO-devel \
      https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git

# install ros package dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    rosdep update && \
    rosdep install -y \
      --from-paths \
        src/ros_tutorials/roscpp_tutorials \
      --ignore-src && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# build ros package source
RUN catkin config \
      --extend /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO && \
    catkin build \
      roscpp_tutorials

# source ros package from entrypoint
RUN sed --in-place --expression \
      '$isource "$ROS_WS/devel/setup.bash"' \
      /ros_entrypoint.sh

# run ros package launch file
CMD ["roslaunch", "roscpp_tutorials", "talker_listener.launch"]
```

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2019-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel_1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/39436/daniel_1337/) on 2019-01-14**:
thank you for your response.
Unfortunately, you do not answer the question how one can execute a `catkin_make` command.

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2019-01-14**:
As `catkin_make` doesn't have the same `--extend` argument to [Explicitly Specifying Workspace Chaining](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#explicitly-specifying-workspace-chaining), I elected show you how to catkin build without resorting to swapping the shell.

**Comment by [dj95](https://answers.ros.org/users/51703/dj95/) on 2020-04-28**:
What does `&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` do?
Why is it required?

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2020-04-29**:
delete all the apt list files since they're big and get stale quickly

- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get
- https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/03e2923e42446dbb830c654d0eec323a0b4ef02a/contrib/mkimage/debootstrap#L235

**Comment by [vvdy](https://answers.ros.org/users/35952/vvdy/) on 2021-09-09**:
I realise this is an old post, but I just wanted to say thank you for this extensive and clear example! It was incredibly helpful in making my own first docker images.

**Comment by [vyke2](https://answers.ros.org/users/97358/vyke2/) on 2022-02-20**:
Thanks! very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to be able to execute a catkin_make command one can use the following command:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c '. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; cd <into the desired folder e.g. catkin_ws>; catkin_make'
```

Thus, the working dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full

# ...
# do what you need to do for example git clone something into ~/catkin_ws/src
# ...

RUN /bin/bash -c '. /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; cd <into the desired folder e.g. ~/catkin_ws/src>; catkin_make'
```

---

Originally posted by [Daniel_1337](https://answers.ros.org/users/39436/daniel_1337/) with karma: 81 on 2019-01-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wthwlh](https://answers.ros.org/users/40343/wthwlh/) on 2019-05-02**:
Ty this works for me. I wonder why

```
RUN /bin/bash -c /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash \
        && catkin_make
```

doesn't work. It is the same layer of container and using same tty. Do you know why it has to be written like that?